# Help with mod_rewrite rule to convert everything after domain to GET

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, apache

Here is what I have in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$\ [NC]
RewriteRule . ?%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

The last three lines converts every thing after example.com/ into GET, so example.com/blahblah will become example.com/?blahblah.

My problem is that when `%3A%2F%2F` is in the url, it leads to a 404 error. e.g: `example.com/blah=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com`
will lead to a 404 not found error instead of `example.com/?blah=http://www.test.com`

Any mod_rewrite gurus can assist?

Here is a rewrite log when this request is made: `http://www.example.com/blah=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com`

```
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55766f8/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /favicon.ico
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55766f8/initial] (1) pass through /favicon.ico
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55766f8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/favicon.ico -> favicon.ico
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55766f8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'favicon.ico'
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55766f8/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/html/] RewriteCond: input='www.example.com' pattern='^example.com' => not-matched
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55766f8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/favicon.ico -> favicon.ico
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55766f8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'favicon.ico'
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55766f8/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/html/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/favicon.ico' pattern='!-d' => matched
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55766f8/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/html/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/favicon.ico.php' pattern='-f' => not-matched
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55766f8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/favicon.ico -> favicon.ico
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55766f8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '.' to uri 'favicon.ico'
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55766f8/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/html/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/favicon.ico' pattern='!-f' => matched
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55766f8/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/html/] RewriteCond: input='/favicon.ico' pattern='!^$\ [NC]' => matched
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55766f8/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/html/] rewrite 'favicon.ico' -> '?/favicon.ico'
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55766f8/initial] (3) split uri=?/favicon.ico -> uri=, args=/favicon.ico
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55766f8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] add per-dir prefix:  -> /var/www/html/
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55766f8/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/html/ -> /
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55766f8/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/] internal redirect with / [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc5586f58/initial/redir#1] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc5586f58/initial/redir#1] (1) pass through /
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc5586f58/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/ -> 
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc5586f58/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri ''
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc5586f58/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir /var/www/html/] RewriteCond: input='www.example.com' pattern='^example.com' => not-matched
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc5586f58/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/ -> 
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc5586f58/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri ''
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc5586f58/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir /var/www/html/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/' pattern='!-d' => not-matched
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc5586f58/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/ -> 
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc5586f58/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '.' to uri ''
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc5586f58/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/] pass through /var/www/html/
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55746e8/subreq] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /example.php
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55746e8/subreq] (1) pass through /example.php
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55746e8/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/example.php -> example.php
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55746e8/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'example.php'
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55746e8/subreq] (4) [perdir /var/www/html/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/example.php' pattern='!-d' => matched
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55746e8/subreq] (4) [perdir /var/www/html/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/example.php.php' pattern='-f' => not-matched
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55746e8/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/example.php -> example.php
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55746e8/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '.' to uri 'example.php'
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55746e8/subreq] (4) [perdir /var/www/html/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/example.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
[www.example.com/sid#7f0fc51e1860][rid#7f0fc55746e8/subreq] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/] pass through /var/www/html/example.php
```

Comment: How much control do you have over your Apache? Can you edit configuration files: httpd.conf or httpd-vhost.conf ?

Comment: Yes I can, I have full control

Comment: In this case you can turn rewrite debugging on (`RewriteLogLevel 9`) and see the rewrite details -- check what may be going wrong and where. That is the best solution as your system can be set up a bit differently than someone else's and what's working on my box may not work in exactly the same manner on your PC/Mac. Enable debug and try accessing that problematic URL, then see the rewrite.log . If unable figure out yourself, post log in your question and we will look together.

Comment: Please see original question as I posted the log there

Comment: Which URL have you tried? I see request for `/favicon.ico`, not `/blah=http..`

Comment: I have tried the same request with a blank log file this time. It is not recording the log when I try that URL for some reason. Almost as if mod_rewrite does not turn on for that URL.

Comment: Yeah -- I have got the same. Must be something that starts even before mod_rewrite. I think Apache detects malformed URL and just stops there without even giving a chance for mod_rewrite. No idea what it may be.

Comment: Would it be safe to not encode the `://` in URL's, for example `http://www.example.com/url=http://test.com&param=1`

Comment: I have found an explanation for the problem in this link: http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3279075.htm

Comment: No. Why don't you do it properly encoded from the very start and pass it as part of query string rather than passing it this way. As you can see currently it has some serious problems which you can avoid if doing it in standard way.

Comment: Nice finding BTW -- it explains my observations.

Comment: I decided to encode the URL using JavaScript's escape() instead of encodeURIComponent() which was converting the forwardslashes to %2F. Using escape() gives me `http://www.example.com/url=http%3A//test.com` instead of `http://www.example.com/url=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.com`

Answer (score 0):

You may try the `NE` flag: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne

Comment: I have added this flag but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similary issue:

your

```
[QSA,L]
```

should be

```
[QSA,L,NE]
```

have a look at

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne

enjoy.

Comment: I have made this modification but it seems to not have any effect.